# Can a skiplist index be built in concurrent threads?

Tags: indexing, data-structures, concurrency, skip-lists

A hash index can be created in parallel using multiple buckets and indexing threads.

Is it possible to distribute the computation* of a skiplist index over multiple CPU cores as well, or does the data structure inherently prevent that?

* *the index building, not the index utilization!*

Comment: Do a Google search on `concurrent skip list`. There are many implementations, including in the Java runtime. The data structure does not inherently prevent concurrency. In fact, building a concurrent skip list is surprisingly straightforward.

Comment: I did that, but what I found was about concurrent **usage** of skiplists, not building them concurrently. Do you have a link that actually shows how it can be **built** with multiple threads?

Comment: The third result on the first page of results is to https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shanir/nir-pubs-web/Papers/OPODIS2006-BA.pdf, "A Provably Correct Scalable Concurrent Skip List." It includes building the list as well as accessing it.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. Google does not show the same results to different people BTW., the times of "n-th page, m-th link" are long over.